# Update state of an object using useState not working

Tags: react-hooks, use-state

Hi I´m doing a tutorial from 1 year ago and seems it is already obsolet.
I´m using folowing versions:
"react": "^18.1.0",
"react-dom": "^18.1.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",

the lines: `setNames([...names, { id: names.length, name }])`
seems not working well, cause it is still empty after using it.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [names, setNames] = useState([]);


  function addNames(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setNames([...names, { id: names.length, name }]);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <form onSubmit={addNames}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name}
          placeholder="add names"
          onChange={(e) => setNames(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        //{names.map((item) => (
        //  <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
        // obsolet, solution:
          {Object.keys(names).map((item) => (
          <li key={names}>{names[item}]</li>
        ))}
      </ul>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You created function `addNames` that seems to be right and you're not using it in `<input>` event `onChange`

Can you call `addNames`in `onChange` and tell me what happens?

Comment: it is called in the line: ```<form onSubmit={addNames}>```

Comment: Oh, look that you're calling `setNames` on `input` instead of `setName`, this can be affecting your code